# NodeJs express save image object to file system

Tags: node.js, image, express

I have a nodeJs express endpoint with the following code:

```
var express = require('express');

const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

var router = express.Router()

router.post("/upload",fileUpload(),(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    res.send('Received!!!');
 });
```

The upload function works well. But how can I save the file uploaded to the file system? The file is an png image as a JSON object in the req.files variable, which contains name(string) and data(buffer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var express = require('express');

const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

var router = express.Router()

router.post("/upload",fileUpload(),(req, res) => {
    let sampleFile = req.files.fileName;

  // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
    sampleFile.mv('./'+sampleFile.name, function(err) {
        if (err)
            return res.status(500).send(err);

        res.send('Received!!!');
    });
 });
```

Hope this help you